# How to use redirect php in python

Tags: python

Please help me... I have a Script... It have written as
MAIN_URL = 'thaisatellite.tv/ftv/'
That is the main thing. And there have more codes called as

```
    self.logoFolder = MAIN_URL + 'logos/'
```

And

```
    self.fileUrl = MAIN_URL + fileName
```

Like these. How can I change this main url to use php file?

thaisatellite.tv/ftv.php this will be the php file and when we going to this php using browser it automatically redirects to 
thaisatellite.tv/ftv/
Please help me. How to add this php link.

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> when we going to this php using browser it automatically redirects to
>   thaisatellite.tv/ftv/

you can do a simple redirect in ftv.php

```
<?php

header("Location: thaisatellite.tv/ftv/");
```

Comment: Yeah. I did this. I made the php file. And when we using the browser rederect works. I want to add this php link to that python code

Comment: I didnt get you ...` I want to add this php link to that python code`

Comment: See Here have added 
MAIN_URL = 'thaisatellite.tv/ftv/'

self.fileUrl = MAIN_URL + fileName

so I want to add MAIN_URL as thaisatellite.tv/ftv.php
But when we add this that didn't working. Because code have MAIN_URL + filename